# Why is meta full of old questions / why did my question get a trivial edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation, meta

**EDIT** - this just happened again recently, so read it again if you're confused.

---

This isn't a question, it's just an update to let people know what happened.

You may have noticed the meta is suddenly flooded with a ton of old posts being bumped up. You also may have noticed one or several inbox notifications about your question being edited, or trivial edits such as adding or removing a single newline from the end of the post.

In the past few days, [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) has very helpfully been going through all of the questions tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) but no status tags (like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), etc) and marking down which ones have already been completed but weren't tagged appropriately, or can't be reproduced, or still need community or team action. (I also went through a few but they did most of the work in this project.)

I initially was going to go through these slowly and edit them a few at a time, but eventually I realized that'd take forever because meta isn't very active. So, I decided to make all of the tag edits all at once and then bump the actually important posts back up with trivial edits.

If you notice a recent and important post has been totally buried that you think should be near the top, feel free to bump it again, or if you think it needs even more attention, you can flag it and I can give it some appropriate attention either via tags, featuring, or posting in chat.

So, in case you were wondering what just happened to meta - basically, a *lot* of 11.

Comment: Just one thing to note: there are still ~40 or so posts that are still missing a [status-] tag. I think it's a smart idea for me to wait a few days/a week - just to let meta resettle a little - before raising these posts for editing. If there's a similar flood in a few days, let this comment be the (slightly more detailed) explanation :)