# I'm in the process of replacing all anonymous imgur images with stack.imgur images, and I need your help

Tags: discussion, editing

As stated on [Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-2023-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stack-exc), all imgur images not associated with a account or the `stack.imgur.com` official corporate instance will be deleted on May 15th.

If we don't replace those links before that date, they will be permanently lost. Some questions and answers may lose unessential fluff, but many will become impossible to understand.

Lucky for us, Glorfindel has already copied some links to the stack.imgur.com domain so all we need to do is edit the posts and replace the links with those given in this document (see also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388726/371052) for more explanation):

- [List of replacement links for images that are properly backed up](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md)
- [List of images not backed up because they were too big, fix these urgently](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25765/91213)
- [List of posts with broken images](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1747560/imgur-links-that-are-about-to-go-down)

Our most important task is to back up images that Glorfindel's script missed, usually because they were above the 2 MB limit. These are those images:

https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25765/91213

Unfortunately the script doesn't record what post these came from so you just need to search.

### Some examples of discussion in other communities:

- https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2724
- https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4589
- https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16762
- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4206
- https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20303
- [More](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388724/371052)

I've already started, mostly because I initially had the wrong query and thought that there were only 17 posts that needed replacing but turns out there are a lot more. I apologize, given the actual number I should have asked on meta first.

There are about 200 images more to go. What should be done with the rest of them?

Comment: If Glorfindel's script has already copied the images to the stack.imgur.com domain, aren't the images themselves safe? The posts that reference the old URLs will still break on May 15th, but the images themselves won't be lost, and we can change the URLs at our leisure. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DLosc Not all images are backed up, especially ones over 2 MB can't be saved to stack.imgur.com without downsizing. There is a list of failed images but it doesn't have post IDs so it's a bit hard to find them, but you could search for those specifically since you are correct the rest is maybe less urgent

Comment: Is everyone able to help with this, or is it only people with access to certain functions (e.g. uploading images to stack.imgur.com)? Where would I upload the size-optimized images, and should we have any guidelines for e.g. keeping EXIF data?

Comment: @JSorngard You need at least 2K rep to make unilateral edits. There is no need to keep EXIF data. You may need to in fact downscale and lower the quality of the images

Comment: @JSorngard To address the "where would I upload" half of your comment, you simply insert the image in a post. Click the "insert image" button (the stylized mountains with a sun over them), browse for or paste the image you want, and click Add picture. The image will be uploaded to stack.imgur.com. I don't think there's a reputation threshold for uploading images, but as mousetail said, there is one for editing. If you have less than 2000 rep, you can make *suggsted* edits, but those have to be approved by another user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This sounds like a great idea!

[Per the guidelines on mass edits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25664/66833), I would ask that people limit themselves to between 5 and 10 edits at a time, depending on how busy `/active` and the front pages are. Further, while certainly not a *requirement*, I'd encourage people to take this opportunity to also answer some older challenges ;)

As for *how* to do this:

- If you have 2000 reputation or more, then feel free to find some of these posts that need replacing, and edit in the updated links for the images at a reasonable rate
- If you have less than 2000 reputation, again, feel free to do the same. Note however, that your edits will require approval by a user with 2000 or more reputation in the [Suggested Edits review queue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits). This means that it may take a bit of time for your edits to go through, and you can only have 5 pending edits. Additionally, while I'm sure multiple people would like more edit reviews, not swamping the review queue is more important, so be extra judicial with how many suggested edits you are submitting in a short period of time
- The images linked in the table in the question might require more effort, such as downsizing or lowering their quality, but should be, as pointed out, of a higher priority for those able to do so

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1749225?data=tamRnBj.png) is a SEDE query that, given a substring, will find all posts with that substring. Notably, SEDE checks against the raw HTML of each post, so links will be found, unlike in normal SE search.

I'd also advising leaving a helpful edit summary when doing these updates. Personally, I've gone with

> `updated image, see meta q 25758`

to point reviewers back to this discussion

Other than that, I encourage you all to get some edits in when you have a bit of free time on the site!

Answer (score 4):

### List of images that are not backed up and need replacing more urgently

Copies this from the post to community wiki it. You can cross out a post if you have finished replacing it.

| Frequency | URL | Failure | Post ID (if known) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <strike>https://i.imgur.com/0ujlnme.jpg</strike> | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| 1 | <strike>https://i.imgur.com/2yE1AjA.jpg</strike> | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [85981](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85981) |
| 1 | <strike>https://i.imgur.com/7wyx4Db.gifv</strike> | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [117382](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117382) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/AnahEIu.gif</s> | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [24490](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24490) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/GO22Mqr.gif</s> | JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] | [119489](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119489) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/Ij4zG7G.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/OYkW5Es.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/QGUxTdh.gif</s> | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/QSWa9Dc.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/SQiYwXM.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/TrbQ70d.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [204471](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204471) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/VupUN46.gifv</s> | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [90700](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90700) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/Zr3tvED.gifv</s> | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [80407](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80407) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/d39hyEc.jpg</s> | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [85981](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85981) |
| 1 | <s>https://i.imgur.com/hntTVNJ.gif</s> | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [188429](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188429) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/iY9DoS4.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [186231](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/186231) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/lfEeYaG.gif | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [153101](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153101) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/m7lOm7L.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/mNFjoiv.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/mR0w3Pib.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [68750](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68750) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/pNLe9i6.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [34459](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34459) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/s5av7Isb.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [68750](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68750) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/tamRnBj.png | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [203782](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203782) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/w3e2JQS.gifv | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [169121](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/169121) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/zmSyRut.mp4 | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [104745](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104745) |

Comment: The 4th one appears to have been moved to https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIQrw.gif

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian feel free to edit it in